# Grepping multiple things with awk

Tags: awk

I want to grep multiple things in a column in a .tsv file but I don't know how to correctly separate the things. I need to grep all the words with either an a,b or c in it. The column in which these letters are is the 6th.

So I already know how to grep one letter but not all. For one letter I have written:

```
awk '{ if ($6 == "a") print $1,$6,$4}'
```

Maybe it is a really simple question but how can I print all letter (a,b,c) at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming that `.tsv` implies tab-separated values:

If you want to print fields 1, 6, and 4 from any record where the sixth field matches `/a/`, `/b/`, or `/c/`:

```
$ awk -F '\t' '$6 ~ /a|b|c/ { print $1, $6, $4 }' inputfile
```

Comment: ty very much, it worked perfectly

Comment: `/[abc]/` should be OK too.

Comment: True, but I was generalizing for `/a|b|c/` being placeholders for larger-than-one-character patterns.  @IlluminaTea, if this solves your problem, please mark this as an accepted answer to indicate that your problem has a solution that passes your muster.

Comment: done and ty again :)

Comment: That will change the tabs in the input to blank chars in the output.

Comment: If tab-separated output is desired (which was not specified), that can be arranged by setting `OFS`.